# ST_ZMax() does not exist in PostGIS

Tags: postgis, postgresql, 3d, mapbox

I'm trying to follow [this example on Mapbox blog](https://www.mapbox.com/tilemill/docs/guides/tilemill-complex-3d-structures/), about using 3D shapes in PostGIS.

The database-query is this:

```
DROP TABLE tilemill_buildings;
CREATE TABLE tilemill_buildings
AS SELECT
ogc_fid,
CAST(size_sqm AS INT) as size_sqm,
CAST(ROUND(CAST(ST_ZMax(wkb_geometry)/2 AS NUMERIC),0) AS INT) AS z_xlarge,
CAST(ROUND(CAST(ST_ZMax(wkb_geometry)/2.5 AS NUMERIC),0) AS INT) AS z_large,
CAST(ROUND(CAST(ST_ZMax(wkb_geometry)/3 AS NUMERIC),0) AS INT) AS z_med,
CAST(ROUND(CAST(ST_ZMax(wkb_geometry)/4 AS NUMERIC),0) AS INT) AS z_small,
wkb_geometry AS wkb_geometry
FROM building_3d
ORDER BY
ST_YMax(Box3D(wkb_geometry)) DESC;
```

...but I get this error:

```
ERROR:  function st_zmax(bytea) does not exist
LINE 5: CAST(ROUND(CAST(ST_ZMax(wkb_geometry)/2 AS NUMERIC),0) AS IN...
                        ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

I have tried to re-install PostGIS twice.  I have run the `CREATE EXTENSION postgis;` command.

Why am I getting this error, and how to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reason is that your wkb_geometry is "well known binary" in bytea type of column, it should be geometry type. You can convert it to geometry using `ST_GeomFromWKB(bytea)` [see this](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.0/ST_GeomFromWKB.html) , if you dont want add new column then replace `ST_ZMax(wkb_geometry)` with `ST_ZMax(ST_GeomFromWKB(wkb_geometry))`

Comment: WOW! Thanks a lot, error message gone! Got a new one now ;) `ERROR:  Polygon must have closed rings`

Comment: http://workshops.boundlessgeo.com/postgis-intro/validity.html that page has a lot of information. Try to use ST_IsValidReason and ST_MakeValid to fix problems on your geoms